# How to fix a 500 Internal Server Error / Servlet Error

Tags: servlets, error-handling, jdeveloper, oc4j

So I recently installed jDeveloper 10.1.3, and the majority of my pages run fine, but on a few of them I run into this error:

```
500 Internal Server Error
Servlet error: An exception occurred. For security reasons, it may not be 
included in  this response. Please consult the application log for details.
```

Now these pages worked in my previous version of jDev, so it shouldnt be a coding error. Also, there is no information in the log to help me troubleshoot.  Can anyone here help?  Also, if more info is needed, Please ask.

Comment: You must be looking at the wrong logs. Without more information, how could we help you?

Comment: @JB Nizet , I am looking at my "Embedded OC4J Server - Log", and I am not sure where else to look, is there another log that may be printing the error stack trace?

Comment: No idea. But now, at least, other readers will know that you're using an embedded OC4J server. You should perhaps add the oc4j tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OC4J stack traces for '500' errors are typically found in the application.log file associated with your application.  For example,

...oc4j_standalone/j2ee/home/application-deployments/yourapp/application.log